# Jenkinsfile Library annotation order

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have Jenkinsfile where I have @Library annotation

```
@Library(['librarty1', 'librarty2', 'librarty3']) _
```

All these libraries are nothing but separate repo having bunch of functions therein which are nothing but groovy scripts.
e.g. library1 has lets say function abc(), library2 also has function abc()

in both libraries function abc() behaves differently.

What I want to do is make sure these libraries are getting loaded in particular order.

e.g library1 gets loaded before library2 and library2 gets loaded before library3.

For above @Library statements sometimes library3 gets loaded before library 1 and 2.. The sequence keeps on changing.

How do I make sure to run them in specific order?

Comment: If one library has a dependency on another, then you should load the dependency in the library itself, and not all simultaneously at the highest scope. That will ensure proper ordering.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Yes, I can do it. My question is more about how to order libraries in annotation itself? Is there any way to do it?